# Gitlab rules with variable assignment does not work

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ee

The variable in the `rules` is not being substituted to "Debug" when the job is run.
The pipeline job is following...

```
variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: obj
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: ".nuget"
  SOURCE_PATH: src/

build:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  tags:
  - fms
  variables:
    DEPLOY_CONFIGURATION: "Release"
  script:
  - echo "Branch => $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  - echo "building with configuration => $DEPLOY_CONFIGURATION"
  - |
    for project in $(find . -type f -name "*.csproj"); do
      echo "Running build for $project"
      dotnet build --configuration $DEPLOY_CONFIGURATION
    done
  extends: ".dotnet-build"
  cache:
    key:
      files:
      - "$SOURCE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project-assets.json"
      - "$SOURCE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*"
      prefix: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
    - "$SOURCE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project-assets.json"
    - "$SOURCE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*"
    - "$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY"
    policy: pull-push
    unprotect: false
    untracked: false
  stage: build
  before_script:
  - dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY
  rules:
  - if: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^develop$|^feature\\/[0-9A-Za-z_-\\+\\.]+$/"
    variables:
      DEPLOY_CONFIGURATION: "Debug"
```

The branch is `feature/pipeline` and the jobs with "Release" not matter what. The Gitlab documentation says otherwise.
I am using `GitLab Enterprise Edition 15.11.6-ee`.
Here is the output when the job starts...

```
$ echo "Branch => $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
Branch => feature/pipeline
$ echo "building with configuration => $DEPLOY_CONFIGURATION"
building with configuration => Release
```

I am testing locally with a Gitlab-runner

`Runtime platform   arch=amd64 os=darwin pid=85068 revision=85586bd1 version=16.0.2`

Comment: I think your regular expression is just [invalid](https://regex101.com/r/uf3kDB/1). I think you accidentally omitted a backslash escape before the last `-` in your expression. Without an escape, it's interpreted as an (invalid) character range.